# glUniformMatrix4fv - INVALID OPERATION?

Tags: opengl

I'm attempting to manually setup a matrix in my vertex shader
purely because I like to learn as much as possible about anything I do usually.

So the problem is that I'm getting an GL_INVALID_OPERATION
when too me my code seems clear as crystal complete.

```
const GLfloat modelviewmatrix[] = {
    1.0f , 0.0f , 0.0f , 0.0f,
    0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f , 0.0f ,
    0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
    0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f
};

GLint locationID = glGetUniformLocation(ShaderPrograms, "modelviewMatrix");

std::cout << "location->" <<locationID << std::endl;
glUniformMatrix4fv(locationID, 1, GL_FALSE, modelviewmatrix);

GLenum error;

error = glGetError();

if (error != GL_NO_ERROR)
{
    std::cout << "not working" << std::endl;
}

if (error == GL_INVALID_OPERATION)
{
    std::cout << "INVALID OPERATION" << std::endl;
}
if (error == GL_NO_ERROR)
{
    std::cout << "No Error! -> CODE CHECKING <-" << std::endl;
}

if (error == GL_INVALID_VALUE)
{
    std::cout << "NO VALUE" << std::endl;
}

if (error == GL_OUT_OF_MEMORY)
{
    std::cout << "NO MEMORY" << std::endl;
}

if (error == GL_STACK_OVERFLOW)
{
    std::cout << "NO OVERFLOW" << std::endl;
}


if (error == GL_INVALID_FRAMEBUFFER_OPERATION)
{
    std::cout << "invalid framebuffer <-" << std::endl;
}

if (error == GL_OUT_OF_MEMORY)
{
    std::cout << "Out of Memory" << std::endl;
}
```

//VERTEX SHADER

```
#version 330 core

layout (location = 0) in vec3 position;

uniform mat4 modelviewMatrix;
uniform mat4 projection;

void main()
{

    gl_Position = modelviewMatrix * vec4(position.x, position.y, position.z, 1.0);
}
```

What could be causing the problem , why is it causing it 
. how did you find out and what did you use too figure it out please?.

OpenGL 3.30+ , GLSL 3.30 core , Win10 64bit.

**figured out what the problem was I was using glUseProgram 
after I was doing uniforms instead of doing that before.**

full source here -> 
http://pastebin.com/zD7YEDjp

Comment: I'm not sure of you know what stackoverflow means based on the debug message.

Comment: Also, you can write vec4(position, 1.0), and openGL fills out the gaps.

Comment: Bálint -> I was always wondering if I could do that or not
thanks for clarifying for me.   Logic is too be aware of as much as possible.

Answer (score 6):

figured out what the problem was I was using glUseProgram after I was doing uniforms instead of doing that before.

Answer (score 4):

You get invalid operation, because you don't use the uniform "projection" in the shader, thus OpenGL deletes it to save memory.

This can be solved by simply referencing it with `projection;`, you don't need to use it.

Like this:

```
#version 330 core

layout (location = 0) in vec3 position;

uniform mat4 modelviewMatrix;
uniform mat4 projection;

 void main()
{

    gl_Position = modelviewMatrix * vec4(position.x, position.y, position.z, 1.0);
    projection;
}
```

Comment: Where does it say I must use every uniform in my shader 
it's their as my second problem to solve hopefully all by myself?.

Comment: I tried removing it and doesn't work so clearly that's not fixing the problem lol.

Comment: @Dominic Hughes if you don't use it, it pretty mich doesn't exist as a uniform, thus glGetUniformLocation returns -1, and you get an invalid operation from glUniformMatrix4fv.

Comment: The compiler's free to remove uniforms you don't use; it's pretty common. It's not the only reason you might get an invalid operation though. Have you read the docs for glUniform*, @DominicHughes? They enumerate the possible scenarios, and you're not currently checking for all of them.

Comment: @DominicHughes not remove it REFERENCE IT

Comment: Okay , okay people... my life on earth..

@Josh Petrie 
I know all the possible problems somewhat:
the shader program not being correctly setup , 
the location of the uniform not being correctly setup , 
the weird data type usage problem *which makes no sense  to me*,
then a few others .

Balint : Do I have to reference it?, 
how do I reference it : 
gl_Position = projection * modelview * vec4(position, 1.0);

or are you talking about in the application 
in which case would I use some of those uniform functions too reference it?

Comment: @DominicHughes you don't need to use it anywhere, I include the code in my post.

Comment: So by putting projection; in the void main of the vertex shader will work?

Comment: I'll give that a go hold on .

Comment: @DominicHughes try it out, I'm not sure as there could be more reasons.

Comment: Tried unforchunately still getting that GL_INVALID_OPERATION
literally am 

location->0
not working
INVALID OPERATION

Hmm it's not a driver bug , can't be..

Comment: @Bálint it's not working, any help very very much appreciated, please.

Comment: @DominicHughes So, location is 0, and still not working?

Comment: @Bálint I figured out what the problem was 
I was using glUseProgram after I was doing uniforms instead of doing that before.

Comment: Is there actual wording in the GLSL specification that guarantees the presence of the uniform if used-but-not-really-used, or is it anecdotal from a particular implementation? I've had rather convoluted chains of uniform references elided in the past, through things like branching on constants like `provably_false ? uf : 0.0`

Comment: @LarsViklund It's present in every  implementation. It's essentially doing the same as any other compiler, if there's an if statement, wich cannot be reached, then it will delete every variables, wich is only used in that part of the code. You can check, wich variables are active with glActiveUniforms or something like that.